# How to access Django media files from Vue.js frontend?

Tags: image, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework backend that serves media files like images, and a Vue.js frontend that consumes this API. I'm trying to display images in my Vue components using the img tag, but the images are not showing up. Instead, I see only broken image icons. However, if I right-click on the icon and select "Open image in new tab", the image opens correctly.

Here's what I've done so far:

- In my Django app's urls.py, I've added the following line to serve media files:
  `urlpatterns = [...] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`
- In my Django app's settings.py, I've set MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL like this:
  `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/') and MEDIA_URL = '/api/media/'`
- In my Vue component's template, I'm using the following code to display an image:
  `<img :src="card.image" alt="Card Image" width="400">`
  where card.image is a string like /api/media/image.jpg.

I've confirmed that the media files are being served correctly by visiting URLs like http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/media/image.jpg in my browser. However, the images are not showing up in my Vue component.

How can I properly access Django media files from my Vue.js frontend? Am I missing something in my setup?